# array_merge results into different keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays. I want to combine them.

**array 1:**

```
Array
(
[100] => 
[50] => 
[CREDIT] => 14.31
[CHEQUE] => 
)
```

**array 2:**

```
Array
(
[id] => 491
[ce_unique_id] => CE144915960926-21
[company_id] => 1
)
```

I am getting this result after merging them with `array_merge()`:

```
Array
(
--->[0] => 
--->[1] => 
[CREDIT] => 14.31
[CHEQUE] => 
[id] => 491
[ce_unique_id] => CE144915960926-21
[company_id] => 1
)
```

And my expected result is:

```
Array
(
--->[100] => 
--->[50] => 
[CREDIT] => 14.31
[CHEQUE] => 
[id] => 491
[ce_unique_id] => CE144915960926-21
[company_id] => 1
)
```

Why the numeric keys are getting changed after merging 2 arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_merge` treats numeric keys differently http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

However the documentation above suggests that merging using the following should work:

```
$newArray = $array1 + $array2;
```